# .focus() not firing for elements added to the DOM with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to use .focus () after adding more input fields with jQuery, but it only works with the input field already present in HTML and not with the ones added.

- For example, if I click on the input field that is in the form, an alert will appear, but if I add more input fields and click on them, nothing will appear.

Is there a solution?
Thanks! :)

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var cont = 1;
        $( "#add-campo" ).click(function() {
            cont++;
            $( '<div class="form-group" id="campo'+cont+'"> <label>Campo: </label> <input type="text" name="titulo[]" placeholder="Digite aqui"> <button id="'+cont+'" class="btn-apagar"> - </button> </div>' ).appendTo( "#formulario" );
        });

        $('form :input').focus(function() {
            alert( "Handler for .focus() called." );
        });

        $( "form" ).on( "click", ".btn-apagar", function() {
            var button_id = $( this ).attr("id");

            $( '#campo' +button_id+'' ).remove();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>ADICIONAR CAMPOS</h1>
<form id="add-pub" method="POST">
    <div id="formulario">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>campo: </label>
            <input type="text" name="titulo[]" placeholder="Digite aqui">
            <button type="button" id="add-campo"> + </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="button" name="PubRot" id="PubRot" value="PUBLICAR">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this...

```
$('form :input').focus(function() {
```

To this...

```
$(document).on('focus', 'form :input', function() {
```

This will cause all future-created elements to retain that binding.  These are called *Delegated Event Handlers*.  The jQuery POD explains both the problem and the solution...

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, place scripts after the elements in the HTML markup or perform event binding inside a document ready handler. Alternatively, use delegated event handlers to attach event handlers....
>
> The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready. (Source: [**jQuery `on` Handler Documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/on/).)

Full working demo with your code sample...

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var cont = 1;
        $( "#add-campo" ).click(function() {
            cont++;
            $( '<div class="form-group" id="campo'+cont+'"> <label>Campo: </label> <input type="text" name="titulo[]" placeholder="Digite aqui"> <button id="'+cont+'" class="btn-apagar"> - </button> </div>' ).appendTo( "#formulario" );
        });

        $(document).on('focus', 'form :input', function() {
            alert( "Handler for .focus() called." );
        });

        $( "form" ).on( "click", ".btn-apagar", function() {
            var button_id = $( this ).attr("id");

            $( '#campo' +button_id+'' ).remove();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>ADICIONAR CAMPOS</h1>
<form id="add-pub" method="POST">
    <div id="formulario">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>campo: </label>
            <input type="text" name="titulo[]" placeholder="Digite aqui">
            <button type="button" id="add-campo"> + </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="button" name="PubRot" id="PubRot" value="PUBLICAR">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Now it's working. I was trying to look for solutions and I couldn't find it on time. Thank you! :)

Comment: Glad to hear it, no problem!

Comment: @ HoldOffHunger The code itself had no problem, just adding the controls could not be done correctly, so the focus did not work, so I modified the code.